# How to improve this piece of code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, enumerator

I am running an online handbag store where handbags can be of four colors - black, brown, orange and red. I have notice that black handbags sell sooner than brown handbags and so forth. That means people like black handbags the most.

On the homepage of the online store I want to select and display 10 bags in a grid layout. So I start by selecting black bags. If I have 10 or more black bags in my inventory then I stop and don't look for the rest of the bags of other colors. However, if I have 5 black bags then I would continue to look for brown bags. After adding those brown bags if I still don't have 10 bags then I look for orange bags and so forth.

Below is my attempt at implementing the solution as Rails model methods:

```
class Handbag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store
  attr_accessor :color
end

class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :handbags

  def handags_for_display
    selected_handbags = []
    ["black", "brown", "orange", "red"].each do |color|
      bags = get_handbags_by_color(color)
      selected_bags += bags
      if selected_bags.size >= 10
        selected_handbags = selected_handbags[0..9]
        break
      end
    end
    selected_handbags
  end

  private
  def get_handbags_by_color(color)
    handbags.where("color = ?", color).limit(10)
  end
end
```

Though this works, I am curious if there is a better way to write it. Particularly, I think this code can be converted to use Ruby's Enumerator.

Comment: This is a better question for [Code Review.SE](http://s.tk/review).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just query the database at once doing something like:

```
@page_offset = ((params[:page].to_i-1)*10) || 0
Handbag.order("color ASC").limit(10).offset(@page_offset)
```

Fortunately the colors already happen to be in alphabetical order.

Comment: It's been fixed to accomodate that case. Also, whoever down voted me please explain why.

Comment: @Dex Your solution works correctly. While working with models I have to get used to thinking more in terms of SQL rather than Ruby. By the way, there is no need for pagination as I never display more than 10 handbags.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a recursive function like this. This works as expected (running this will give you `{:black => 1, :brown => 8, :orange => 1}`), and you can just change the get_handbags_by_color to work with Rails instead.

```
@bags = {
  :black => 1,
  :brown => 8,
  :orange => 10,
  :red => 10
}

@handbag_order = [:black, :brown, :orange, :red]
@max_bags = 10

def get_handbags_by_color(color,limit)
  num = @bags[color]
  num > limit ? limit : num
end

def handbags_for_display(index = 0, total = 0)
  color = @handbag_order[index]
  return {} unless color
  handbags = {color => get_handbags_by_color(color,@max_bags - total)}
  total += handbags.values.inject{|sum,x| sum+x}

  handbags.merge!(handbags_for_display(index+1, total)) unless(total >= @max_bags)
  handbags
end

handbags = handbags_for_display
```

Comment: Just to differentiate between the accepted answer, this one will allow you to change the order whenever you want, change the limit easily, and will only run as many queries as necessary to reach the limit

Answer (score -1):

```
def handags_for_display
     handbags = Array.new
     [{ :color => 'black', :count => 5 }, { :color => 'brown' , :count => 2 }, { :color => 'orange', :count => 1 }, { :color => 'red', :count => 1}].each do |handbag|
          handbags+=Handbag.where("color = ?", handbag[:color]).limit(handbag[:count])
     end
     handbags
end
```